# OOP Design considering no modifications to existing design

Tags: java, object-oriented, interfaces, abstract-class

The question is:

```
interface Animal {
    void eat();
}

class Lion implements Animal{    
    public void eat(){
        //do somethng
    }
}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal lion = new Lion();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
    }
}
```

The requirement is to calculate how many times the eat method is called without modifying the interface and the class itself.

One way is to extend the lion class and get the results but for every object extending the class we will have to create such classes.

Is there any optimized way to do this.

Publish Subscribe is one way but we don't have the permissions to modify the interface or the Lion class itself.

Comment: I assume "OOPS" is a typo.

Comment: Just to clarify: Is your problem that you want to extend the behavior of all `Animal` classes, but cannot modify the code of `Animal` or its existing subclasses?

Comment: If the title was useful,  I would have upvoted this question, when I saw the title in the question list I assumed this question needed a downvote until I read the question.   Sorry I can't think of a good title.

Comment: Sorry that the title is disappointing a lot here , i am changing it to a more suitable one here, adding tags for the terms instead. OOPS was for Object Oriented Programming System. Correct me if that is incorrect

Comment: "One way is to extend the lion class and get the results but for every object extending the class we will have to create such classes" Huh? You would just replace all instantiations of Lion with instantiations of you Lion descendant. How is that a lot of work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the Decorator Pattern to add additional responsibilities to an Animal without subclassing.

[image]

```
public interface Animal {
    void eat();
}

public class Lion implements Animal {
    public void eat() {
        // do something
    }
}

/* In the original Decorator pattern, 
the decorator is an abstract class, 
but for the sake of brevity, 
in this example it's a concrete class. */

public class AnimalWithEatCountDecorator implements Animal {
        private Animal animalWeWantToCountEats;
        private int eatCount=0;

        public AnimalWithEatCountDecorator(Animal animal) {
            this.animalWeWantToCountEats= animal;
        }
        
        public void eat(){ 
            this.animalWeWantToCountEats.eat();
            this.eatCount++;
        }
        
        public int getEatCount() {
            return this.eatCount;
        }   
        
}  

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalWithEatCountDecorator lion = new AnimalWithEatCountDecorator(new Lion());
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        
        System.out.println(lion.getEatCount());
    }

}
```

### UPDATE

If we want to be more faithful to the Decorator Pattern we can not use the `getEatCount()` getter at all, and instead inject a Counter object in the constructor.

```
public interface Counter {
    public void increment();
    public int getCount();
}

/* I will omit the trivial implementation of Counter */ 

public class AnimalWithEatCountDecorator implements Animal {
        private Animal animalWeWantToCountEats;
        private Counter counterThingy;
        
        public AnimalWithEatCountDecorator(Animal animal, Counter counterThingy) {
            this.animalWeWantToCountEats= animal;
            this.counterThingy=counterThingy;
        }
        
        public void eat(){ 
            this.animalWeWantToCountEats.eat();
            this.counterThingy.increment();;
        }
        
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter counterThingy = new CounterThingy();
        AnimalWithEatCountDecorator lion = 
                new AnimalWithEatCountDecorator(new Lion(), counterThingy);
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        
        System.out.println(counterThingy.getCount());


    }

}
```

[image: Same solution with no pattern-disrupting getter]

Comment: Yes, but: 1. Don't call classes "Decorator". Decorator is a technical term, classes are named using the domain. It's an `Animal`, not a `Decorator`. 2. Don't have getters. To be composable (and maintainable) your "decorator" should conform to the interface exactly. Otherwise you'll won't be able to stack these things.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Why do you mean by "stack these things"?

Comment: If you use composition over inheritance, you'll often have more then one "decorator". To use more then one, i.e. to plug multiple layers of them together, you can't add methods, because those will not be visible on the top.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam How else would you expect to access the count if not by a getter? Would you expect to pass a `Counter` into the `new EatCountingAnimal(theLion, myCounter)` from which you could later get the count?

Comment: @Bergi As a rule of thumb with object-orientation I would expect the logic to be *contained fully* in the decorator, regardless of what this logic is. This is important! It means I don't "get" the count to do something with it, the decorator *does* the thing that needs to be done. You could pass in more collaborators in the constructor, as you rightly pointed out, but that should not change the point above.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Ah, I see what you mean from your answer, but that just logs a count three times, it cannot really produce (once) a count of how often something happened to the lion because it wouldn't know when the "test sequence" ends.

Comment: @Bergi I suspect you are thinking that such a counter decorator should be generic, re-usable and work in different contexts therefore it could/should not know specific things in this scenario. This is a trap! Things should be as specific as needed. If your use-case requires knowing boundaries of a test sequence, then have it know that. *Or*, if there is a thing called `TestSequence`, then it may take this functionality from `Animal`. My point remains that logic shouldn't be broken up or separated from its data.

Comment: @Bergi The decorator could be constructed with a consumer or callback which is called every time the animal eats.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I am intrigued by your discussion. Yet I don't see how your LoggingAnimal is superior to a decorated Animal with a getCount().
From an automated testing standpoint, I would pass the Animal into some blackbox and later check if it was properly used. For that i would need some data channel out of the Animal (logging seems like a sneaky backdoor to me).
Are you looking at it from a Production/Manual Log Evaluation perspective?

Comment: @TheHowlingHoaschd Robert is thinking about doing `lion = new EatLoggingAnimal(new RunCountingAnimal(new EatCountingAnimal(new Lion)))`, where `lion.getEatCount()` would not be available on the resulting object.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for illuminating to me, what Robert meant by "stacking".
I would then agree with you or Polygnome that a callback/counter should be passed to the decorator's constructor.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: I like your advice, but I prefer YAGNI. I'll start with a getter to extract the count, and refactor later if I need something more sophisticated.

Comment: I agree, I think `AnimalWithEatCountDecorator` is a good name, when using well known design patterns it's good to have the name there, so the next reader can understand what's going on.  As for whether it's a getter or not, that depends on how this class is going to be used, so long as it's well encapsulated, think of how it's to be used to determine what specifically to implement.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Would you mind showing the modifications to the `main()` method so it's more obvious what you're doing?

Comment: @SeldomNeedy The `Test` class containing the `main` method is at the very end of the code block.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Ah. Missed the scrollbar there. Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi _"but that just logs a count three times, it cannot really produce (once) a count of how often something happened to the lion because it wouldn't know when the "test sequence" ends"_ Whether the decorator triggers an injected logger to write a message, or triggers an injected lambda/method/event which increments a counter, requires the exact same implementation. The decorator defines the trigger logic around `Eat` being called, but it doesn't need to define the response when the trigger is triggered. Inject that into the decorator, it improves the decorator's reusability.

Comment: @Flater Yes, but Robert's implementation from [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/414902/66652) doesn't have this injection, instead it's a fully self-contained logger. That's all I was remarking. I guess someone should write up an answer with a code example for a lambda-calling decorator.

Comment: @Bergi We can get rid of the getter ans instead inject an `Counter` object in the constructor, so after calling `eat()` the code can do `counterObjt.increment;`. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: @Bergi: Logs are mostly considered as static, i.e. one log to catch all messages from all instances. This eating counter, however, would be instance-based (i.e. per `Lion` object). The log can be hardcoded without issue since every instance is expected to write to the same log (in this example code), but a specific lion's eat counter cannot reasonably account for knowing which counter to increment when, hence the need for injecting that. Note also that because the log requires no further action, it's much easier to hide it than an explicitly retrievable counter is.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Thanks, that's what I was suggesting.

Comment: @Bergi Added update an the end.

Answer (score 22):

Perfect time for composition. Create a new implementation of `Animal` that does the counting, but also delegates the "real" function. Like this:

```java
public final class LoggingAnimal implements Animal {
   private final Animal delegate;
   private int eatCount = 0;

   public LoggingAnimal(Animal delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public void eat() {
      eatCount++;
      delegate.eat();
      log("Animal ate {} times", eatCount); // Pseudo-functionality
   }
}
```

You don't have to modify any of the existing classes, and you can plug this together with any implementation of `Animal` you want. Use this way:

```java
Animal lion = new LoggingAnimal(new Lion());
lion.eat();
```

Comment: Totally looks like a Decorator/Wrapper for me. While it technically could be called a Composition, I'm somewhat against using this term when only a single object is 'composed' into a new thing.

Comment: Better to call `eatCount++;` after then `delegate.eat();`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class with the new behavior. Then update `main` in the `Test` class.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal lion = new AnimalThatKeepsAMealLog();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
    }
}
```

or just read the Test file and count the number of times you called `eat()`. I'm guessing the answer is gonna be three.

Comment: How is this being upvoted, this goes totally against the actual question at hand.

Comment: @TristanMaxson really? Nothing in the requirements given asked us to maintain the current lion behavior. We're free to make an animal that does whatever we like when it's told to eat so long as it counts meals and uses the same interface. In fact every answer here followed this answers method of overriding the behavior. Which is fine. Since it's a test I stuck with a simple mock. Others wanted to show off the decorator pattern. Which also works.

Comment: @TristanMaxson  the question asks to maintain *the interface* and *the class*. Namely, I read that as the `Animal` interface and the `Lion` class. This answer changes neither, so I don't see how it's failing the requirement.

Comment: Anyway, decorator or mock, what ends up getting tested isn't `Lion`. These answers test the `lion.eat()` calling code. In it's current form, not really worth testing.

Comment: @VLAZ no it doesn't anymore, since candied_orange did a sneaky edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a different approach, that will allow you to avoid having 50 classes for tasks only done a few times. It's a more generic one, very useful in technical aspects, not as much in business ones, can still be very useful tho.

btw Builder is just to illustrate, of course you don't have to use it like that, preEat/postEat are important here

```
class PointcutAnimal implements Animal {
    private Runnable preEat;
    private Runnable postEat;
    @NonNull
    private Animal downstream;
    
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        if(preEat != null)
            preEat.run();
        
        downstream.eat();
        
        if(postEat != null)
            postEat.run();
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger eatCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
        Animal lion = PointcutAnimal.builder(new Lion())
            .postEat(eatCount::getAndIncrement)
            .build();
            
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        
        System.out.println(eatCount.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive.  Aspect oriented programming done manually.

Comment: Just missing the builder method that sets `downstream`.

Comment: Not sure if you are being sarcastic :D I wouldn't dare using Aspects on POJO/model objects etc. I don't like Aspects in general, I use them only for pure background tasks like logging in library code, but when I need an output (the 'eat count') - no no no.

Comment: As to the builder - `.builder(new Lion())` sets the `downstream`, done this way because it is required here, so to even get the builder you need to pass that object (as opposed to pre/post eat). Didn't write the whole builder, not the clue of this answer.

Comment: no sarcasm at all. As specified this is a logging problem. I like aspect solutions that don’t force what they’re advising to know about them. Here Lion doesn’t know a thing. But without a wide spread need for that logging, rather than an aspect library, I’d prefer to see a focused solution like yours.